# How to make Nginx handle send_file requests on Amazon Linux with Ruby and Passenger Standalone

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, x-sendfile

I cant manage to make Nginx handle my file downloads. They keep being sent by Rails directly, which is not a good idea for known reasons.

Files to be downloaded by an iOS app are zipped on an Amazon EC2 instance and put into a folder called /var/app/current/tmp/zip on request. I made sure the files actually are available in that folder by logging into the instance.

Now from within a rails controller the files are sent like this:

```
send_file("tmp/zip/#{filename}.zip", :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "documents.zip", :x_sendfile => true, :disposition => "inline")
```

The client receives the files with headers:

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="documents.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/zip
Date:Tue, 27 Sep 2016 06:58:51 GMT
Server:nginx/1.8.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.60
Status:200 OK
transfer-encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:Phusion Passenger 4.0.60
X-Request-Id:6809ca4a-fad5-4cf6-8b98-a8176d26487a
X-Runtime:9.405918
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

The above tells me that the file is sent from rails and was not handled by Nginx as it should.

The configuration I'm using:

config/environments/production.eb:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

ebextensions/nginx.config:

```
files:
  '/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf':
    content: |            
      proxy_connect_timeout 1000;
      proxy_send_timeout 1000;
      proxy_read_timeout 1000;
      send_timeout 1000;

      server {

        proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;        
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /var/app/current/tmp/zip/=/storage/;

        #passenger_set_header X-Sendfile-Type "X-Accel-Redirect";
        #passenger_env_var HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING /var/app/current/=/storage/;
        #passenger_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;

        location /storage/ {
          root /var/app/current/tmp/zip/;
          internal;
        }
      }
```

Still nginx doesnt handle the file transfer. Server logs show:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/passenger.log
-------------------------------------
App 28302 stderr: X-Accel-Mapping header missing
```

I also tried the "passenger_" directives but they fail with:

```
>sudo service nginx restart
unknown directive "passenger_set_header" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf:17
```

My last try was to set the X-header from within the controller directly:

```
response.headers["X-Accel-Redirect"] = "/var/app/current/tmp/zip/#{filename}.zip"
```

This fails with:

production.log

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/var/app/current/tmp/zip/FxPNa3nB--Kqt8L51PT3sg.zip", FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/var/app/current/tmp/zip/FxPNa3nB--Kqt8L51PT3sg.zip"):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.60) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.60) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.60) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.60) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

I'm running on Amazon EBS 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 with Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone).

Any help much appreciated.